# Defining what type of casting based on IPv4 address

Tags: ipv4, ip-address, multicast, broadcast, networking

I'm kinda new to networking. I have a small question, how can I determine what type of casting (unicast, multicast or broadcast) is it based on IPv4 address. For example: 142.55.172.200

I tried to search up but I still don't understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For IPv4, unicast addresses are in the `0.0.0.0` to `223.255.255.255` range*, multicast addresses are in `224.0.0.0` to `239.255.255.255` address range.

*Broadcast addresses are more complicated. There is the limited broadcast address (`255.255.255.255`) that works on all networks, but there is also a network broadcast address that is the last address in a network.

---

For a full explanation of IPv4 network addressing, see [this two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499).

Answer (score 3):

- 0.0.0.0 to 223.255.255.255 are normally unicast.
- 224.0.0.0 to 239.255.255.255 are multicast
- 240.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.254 are reserved and will most likely never be allocated. Some operating systems refuse to work with them at all, others treat them as regular unicast addresses.
- 255.255.255.255 is limited broadcast. This will be broadcast to all systems on the same "link" as the sender.
- The last address of a subnet (other than a /31) is also broadcast. This can be used to broadcast to a specific subnet, either if a system is multi-homed or if the router serving that subnet allows "directed broadcasts"

Directed broadcast is nearly always disabled nowadays, since it is a useful tool for attackers.

Unfortunately there is no way to reliablly distinguish a unicast address from a broadcast one. Since subnets can vary in size and some systems may not use traditional subnets at all there is no general way to determine the "last address of a subnet".

Comment: And the "special case" /31 point-to-point subnet has no broadcast. (it's an address saving hack.)